# why are the queues I created empty even after putting elements in them?

Tags: java, queue, stack

I tried a few different ways, but I always get the empty list problem. What I want is to be able to get the values ​​from the lists, stack them in a specific order and then remove them from the stack showing the name of each patient and the priority level one by one in the terminal.

```
public class StackUp {
    private Queue<Patient> listLeve = new Queue<>();
    private Queue<Patient> listNormal = new Queue<>();
    private Queue<Patient> listModerado = new Queue<>();
    private Queue<Patient> listSevero = new Queue<>();

    public void addPacientesFila(Patient x) throws Exception{
        if (x.getPrioridade() == 0) {
            listLeve.enqueue(x);
        } 
        else if (x.getPrioridade() == 1) {
            listNormal.enqueue(x);
        } 
        else if (x.getPrioridade() == 2) {
            listModerado.enqueue(x);
        } 
        else if (x.getPrioridade() == 3) {
            listSevero.enqueue(x);
        } 
        else {
            throw new Exception("Número de prioridade errado"); 
        }
    }

    public Stack<Patient> empilharPacientes() throws Exception {
        Stack<Patient> pilha = new Stack<>();
        
        pilha.push(listNormal.dequeue());
        pilha.push(listSevero.dequeue());
        pilha.push(listModerado.dequeue());
        pilha.push(listSevero.dequeue());
        pilha.push(listLeve.dequeue());
        pilha.push(listModerado.dequeue());
        pilha.push(listSevero.dequeue());

        return pilha;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is a good way to do this.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GestaoHospital {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String nome;
    private int cpf;
    private int prioridade;
    StackUp empilha = new StackUp();

    public void registrarPaciente() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Informe o nome do paciente: ");
        nome = scanner.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite o cpf do paciente: ");
        cpf = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Informe o nível de prioridade do paciente: ");
        prioridade = scanner.nextInt();

        Patient pessoa = new Patient(nome, cpf, prioridade);

        empilha.addPacientesFila(pessoa);
    }

    public void atenderPacientes() throws Exception {
        Stack<Patient> pilha = new Stack<>();
        List<Patient> lista = new ArrayList<>();

        pilha = empilha.empilharPacientes();
        lista = pilha.popAll();

        for(Patient paciente : lista) {
            System.out.println("O paciente " + paciente.getNome() + " de CPF " + paciente.getCpf() +
                    " foi atendido com o nível de prioridade " + paciente.getPrioridade());

            System.out.println("Pressione <ENTER> para atender o próximo paciente...");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Random random = new Random();
        StackUp pacientes = new StackUp();
        GestaoHospital atender = new GestaoHospital();

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            int numeroAleatorio = random.nextInt(4);
            Patient exemplo = new Patient("Zé", i, numeroAleatorio);
            
            pacientes.addPacientesFila(exemplo);
        }

        atender.atenderPacientes();        
    }
}
```

The Main method is just being used to test whether the program manages to create patients, line them up according to their priority level and if it manages to remove them from the stack with the atenderPacientes() method.

Comment: Are you asking why the entries in `pacientes` are not showing in `empilha`?

Comment: Please share the Queue implementation you are using. It is not java.util.Queue.

Comment: In the main method you create 10 `Patient`s  and add them to `pacientes` (which happens to be a local `StackUp` instance within the main method). Then you want to give treatments by calling `atender.atenderPacientes();` - but `atender.atenderPacientes();` reads the patients from `empilha` which is a different `StackUp` instance.